# Anonymous functions in println in Scala

Tags: scala

Let's say we do

```
object Test {
    def main(args: Array[String]){
        println(() => "2pac")     // passing anon function 
        println((() => "shakur")()) // passing anon function, with empty args
        println(biggie)           // passing named function, no args
    }

    def biggie = "smalls"
}
```

That will print out

```
<function>
shakur
smalls
```

Why does the anonymous function, with the same type signature as the named function, require explicit empty args? Why does `biggie` get called when it's printed but the `2pac` function doesn't?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let's go line by line:

```
println(() => "2pac")
```

here you are passing a function to println.  Remember a function in Scala is just an object, so println is merely calling the `toString` method on the `Function0` type, which just always outputs `<function>` (actually for me it outputs `<function0>`)

```
println((() => "shakur")())
```

Now you are invoking the anon function before it is passed to `println`, so instead of receiving a `Function0` object, it receives the return value of the function and just outputs the string

```
println(biggie)
```

Lastly, here `biggie` is not just a `Function0`, it is a **nullary** function, meaning the function executes whenever it is referenced and does not explicitly require invocation `()`.  This is because you defined it without a parameter list, as opposed to an empty parameter list.  So when you call `println(biggie)`, the `biggie` function is evaluated and its result is sent to `println`

If you call `println(biggie _)`, the underscore tells the compiler *not* to evaluate the function, and instead it passes the function itself to `println`.  Likewise, if you defined `biggie` as:

```
def biggie() = "smalls"
```

When you call `println(biggie)` it then behaves the same as passing a 0-arg anon function.

Comment: +1. Nicely detailed. But you should replace "nullary function" with "nullary method". The concept of "method" and "function" are often used interchangeably, and the distinction often does not matter much, but here it does: a nullary function won't automatically be applied even when the the (empty) parameter list is missing, while a nullary method will (if used in a context where some type other than a function is expected). Plus methods make the distinction between a nullary method and a no-arg method, while function only can be nullary (a no-arg function is not somthing that exists in scala).

Comment: `def`s aren't functions, they are methods.

Comment: @RégisJean-Gilles @pedrofurla Actually, `def` are functions by Scala's Specification, much as I dislike that terminology. The question is using, intentionally or not, the specification's terminology.

Comment: Well this is true, so point taken, but I would argue that here the specification itself uses a lazy wording. I know this might seem presomptuous, but the thing is there are **very** real differences between a *method*  and a *function* (or as per the spec's wording, a *function* introduced by `def` and an actual function object), so we should really strive to make the disctinction clear. And I know I'm not the only one to think like this. Trying to use the word *function* everywhere might look like a simplification (and might make scala look more functional) but it's travesting reality.